# Get index of child with prop in Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

Let's say I have this component markup:

```
<MyComponent>
    <ComponentChild />
    <ComponentChild target />
    <ComponentChild />
</MyComponent>
```

How can I determine the **index** of the child with `target` in `MyComponent`?

I've tried the following:

```
let index;
const childArray = React.Children.toArray(this.props.children);
const item = childArray.find((child) => {
    if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
        const clone = React.cloneElement(child as React.ReactElement<any>);
        return clone.props['target'];
    }
});
index = childArray.indexOf(item); // <-- this line causes the error
```

Which results in this error: `error TS2345: Argument of type 'string | number | ReactElement<any> | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReactChild'.`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Inside the "parent" component you can use `props.children`:

https://www.reactenlightenment.com/basic-react-components/6.8.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to work:

```
let index;
if (this.props.children) {
    React.Children.forEach(this.props.children, (child, i) => {
        if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
            const clone = React.cloneElement(child as React.ReactElement<any>);
            if (clone.props['target']) {
                index = i;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Still curious about that error I got before though...